# 8x1 header in OrCAD

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, footprint, orcad

I'm trying to create a LCD Arduino Shield for the Arduino Uno using OrCAD. I want to add 8 pin through hole to solder headers into them. However, the 8 pin header in OrCAD library under Connector library is 4x2 header in the PCB editor. But I want a 8x1 header for Arduino and two 8x1 header for my 16pin 16x2 LCD as well.

Or is there a way I can modify the footprint of the jumper header in Connector library?

Comment: just learn how to use Eagle, and use the sparkfun libraries..

Comment: Do you know anything about Eagle to OrCAD translator using nsWare?

Comment: No, sorry. I use Altium and KiCAD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your own footprint.  If you do any amount of PC design, you *will* have to make your own schematic symbols and PCB footprints - you can't expect the CAD developers to supply symbols and footprints for every conceivable part.  (and you should save any parts you create in your own library, so you won't loose them when you upgrade the CAD package.)

Comment: I created an 8 pin header part in Schematic Capture but I'm not sure how to create a corresponding PCB footprint for the schematic symbol. Thanks

Comment: You could copy an existing footprint (perhaps the 4x2 one you mention) and shuffle the pads around to suit your 8x1 connector.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Which version do you use? i use layout plus 10.5 if it is 10.5 you can use below

8x1 pcb footprint:

```
BLKCON.100/VH/TM1SQ/W.100/8;
```

16x1 footprint:

```
BLKCON.100/VH/TM1SQ/W.100/16;
```

Also you can create how you want it

Comment: I use OrCAD PCB editor and Schematic capture 16.5. I will look for those footprints. Thanks

Comment: Those don't exist for OrCAD PCB editor. I looked through the pcb footptrint library and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, i edited my answer. i don't use 16.5 version. manufacturer is changed after 10.5 version so i use still 10.5.maybe you can try make your own footprint. i am sure you can find a video in youtube.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I ended up making my own footprint. I'm hoping the dimensions are correct. My goal is to make an Arduino shield. Do you know anything about EagletoOrCAD translator?

Comment: unfortunately i don't. Actually Arduino headers have standart dimension and dimension is 2.54mm/0.1 inch

Answer (score 1):

@PeterBennett is correct. You need to be able to make your own.  Of course, making a part in OrCAD kinda sucks :)

I use [Library Expert](http://www.pcblibraries.com/LibraryExpert/) whenever I can.  The "Lite" version is free, and creates IPC-7351-compliant footprints from the part's dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, create it yourself. This is an easy one compared to some of the complex footprints you'll see, such as USB connectors and the like, but will allow you to begin to explore the package creator.

Try the "package symbol (wizard)" tool under File > New. This makes it super simple, you basically just have to specify the pitch (likely 0.100" = 100 mil), package length and width, and ref des (J). The length and width you should get from the datasheet, but are most likely approximately 0.800" (800 mil) and 0.100" (100 mil) respectively.